Approaches to nonstandard measure theory
So I don't really know anything about measure theory or nonstandard measure theory or nonstandard analysis or anything like that, but my friend who is taking measure theory next semester told me about non-measurable sets which peaked my interest so I looked into Vitali sets and basically got this understanding that the problem comes from trying to add up countably many uncountable sets since you get the same problem where you can "subtract" the set of even numbers from the natural numbers and be left with either the odd numbers or nothing based on how you match up the terms.
Anyways I thought about it for a bit and basically I came up with the idea of getting rid of the requirement that the measure of the countable union of disjoint sets be equal to the sum of the measures of the individual disjoint sets. (but you still keep this relation for finitely many sets)
And then I was thinking you can say something like the Vitali set sort of has an "infinitesimal" measure where the union of finitely many of the sets is (essentially) 0, but if you take a union of countably many sets it suddenly has nonzero measure (and the resulting measure you get can change based on how you take the countable union).
And the only other thing is then induction doesn't really hold (but I was thinking since that's an axiom this could maybe be an example of a system where induction doesn't hold?)
And I tried googling some of this to see if it was a thing and found some stuff about nonstandard measure theory and nonstandard analysis but I don't really want to do all the work to look into those more and see if they are what I'm thinking of.
TLDR: Can someone who has experience with nonstandard measure theory or nonstandard analysis tell me if the idea of removing the "countable disjoint sum requirement" for measures to get sets with a sort of "infinitesimal" measure is a thing or am I cranking?

There exist finitely additive extensions of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)$ that are total (every set is assigned a measure) and symmetric under translations modulo $1$.  For a discussion see

Ciesielski, Krzysztof.  How good is lebesgue measure?. The Mathematical Intelligencer 11 (1989), 54--58.

This result was also proved via infinitesimal techniques in

Bernstein, Allen; Wattenberg, Frank.
Non-standard measure theory, in Applications of model theory
to algebra, analysis, and probability, edited by W.A.J. Luxemburg
(Holt, Rinehart, and Winston, New York, 1969), pp. 171--185.

